# If $a,b,c,d$ are the roots of the equation biquadratic equation $x^4+px^3 +qx^2+rx+s=0$ , find the value of $\Sigma a^2b^2$.

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

If $a,b,c,d$ are the roots of the equation biquadratic equation $x^4+px^3 +qx^2+rx+s=0$
, find the value of $\Sigma a^2b^2$.

My solution goes like this:

> Since, $a,b,c,d$ are the roots of the equation biquadratic equation $x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+s=0$ so, we have, $\Sigma a=-p$,$\Sigma ab=q$,$\Sigma abc=-r$,$ abcd=s$. Now.$$\Sigma a^2b^2=\Sigma (ab)^2-2\Sigma a^2bc-6abcd.$$Also, $$\Sigma a^2bc=\Sigma a\Sigma abc -4abcd=pr-4s$$. Thus, $\Sigma a^2b^2=\Sigma (ab)^2-2\Sigma a^2bc-6abcd=q^2-2pr+2s.$

However, in this solution when I wrote the expression $\Sigma a^2b^2=\Sigma (ab)^2-2\Sigma a^2bc-6abcd$, I had to calculate the value of $(ab+ac+...+cd)^2$ manually and then I could write in this "above -short form"(which looks simplified just because of the notations used). Same goes for the calculation of $$\Sigma a^2bc=\Sigma a\Sigma abc -4abcd=pr-4s$$ . There , I had to calculate $(a+b+c+d)(abc+...+bcd)$ manually . However, these manual calculations are unusually large as well as huge . Is there any other way to directly predict $$\Sigma a^2bc=\Sigma a\Sigma abc -4abcd=pr-4s$$ and $\Sigma a^2b^2=\Sigma (ab)^2-2\Sigma a^2bc-6abcd$? Or is direct calculation the only way to arrive at these results?

Comment: Nitpick: The equation is *quartic* as in degree four. A *biquadratic equation* has the form $x^4+ax^2+b=0$ with cubic and linear terms missing.

Comment: When working with symmetric polynomials you can avoid huge expansions by letting symmetry work for you (and let it take care of itself). The remaining questions (at the level of individual monomials) are combinatorial in nature: in how many ways can I get this term, when I multiply this and this? For example
$$(\sum a)(\sum abc)= \sum a^2bc+4abcd,$$
because the only way to get the specific monomial $a^2bc$ to appear in the product on the left is to pick $a$ from the first factor and $abc$ from the second. But you can get $abcd$ in four different ways.

Comment: This kind of thinking can be developed into an algorithm, but it may be better to just work out a few low degree cases.

Comment: If your equation is bi-quadratic, then one can assume $a = -b$ and  $c = -d$, which makes the $\sum{a^2b^2} = \sum{abcd}$, where this is an application of Vieta's formula.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you! However, can you please elaborate your answer ? ...

Comment: What does your sum mean?  $a$ and $b$ are particular roots of your polynomial.  What is the sum over?  What is varying?

Answer (score 2):

[Symmetric functions](http://www.symmetricfunctions.com) are
an interesting and actively explored field of study. Suppose
we have a finite but arbitrary set of variables
$\{a,b,c,\dots\}.$ Define
some elementary symmetric functions
$$ e_1 \!=\! \Sigma a \!=\! a\!+\!b\!+\!c\!+\!\dots ,\;
 e_2 \!=\! \Sigma ab \!=\! ab\!+ac\!+\!bc\!+\!\dots, \;
e_3 \!=\! \Sigma abc \!=\! abc\!+\!\dots. $$
A natural question is how to find $\Sigma a^2.$ First, compute
$$ e_1^2 = (\Sigma a)(\Sigma a) = \Sigma aa+ \Sigma ab +\Sigma ba =
\Sigma a^2 + 2e_2 $$
which is a generalization of $(a+b)^2 = (a^2+b^2) + 2(ab)$ to
many variables. The result is
$\Sigma a^2 = e_1^2 - 2e_2.$ Similar results can be found.
For example,
$$ e_1e_2 = (\Sigma a)(\Sigma ab) = \Sigma a^2b +\Sigma bab
+3\Sigma abc = \Sigma a^2b + 3e_3. $$ The result is
$\Sigma a^2b = e_1e_2 - 3e_3.$ You have to be careful to count
the monomials with proper multiplicities. Another example is
$$ e_1e_3 = (\Sigma a)(\Sigma abc) = \Sigma a^2bc + 
\Sigma babc +\Sigma cabc+ 4e_4 = \Sigma a^2bc +4e_4 $$ which
generalizes. Final example is
$$ e_2e_2 = (\Sigma ab)(\Sigma ab) = \Sigma a^2b^2 +
 2\Sigma a^2bc + 6\Sigma abcd = \Sigma a^2b^2 + 2\Sigma a^2bc
+ 6e_4. $$ Combine with previous results
to get $\Sigma a^2b^2 = e_2^2 -2e_3e_1 +2e_4.$

You can check this result in the special case where all of
the variables are equal.

Comment: Right: the concerned topic is symmetric functions.

Comment: @Somos How did you write $$ e_1^2 = (\Sigma a)(\Sigma a) = \Sigma aa+ \Sigma ab +\Sigma ba =
\Sigma a^2 + 2e_2 $$? I take it you perform this for $n$ number of variables, right? But then how did you actually compute it?...

Comment: @Franklin I thought of it as $(\Sigma a)(\Sigma a) = (\sum_i v_i)(\sum_j v_j) = \sum_{i,j} v_i v_j = \sum_i v_iv_i + \sum_{i<j}v_iv_j +\sum_{i>j}v_iv_j = \\\sum_i v_i^2 + 2\sum_{i<j}v_iv_j = \Sigma a^2+2\Sigma ab = \Sigma a^2+2e_2.$